About strictly convex norm
Let X be a normed vector space. $\| . \|$ is a norm.
we said this norm is a strictly convex norm if $$ \forall x,y \in X :  \| x\| \le 1,  \|y\| \le 1 \Rightarrow  \| \frac{x+y}{2} \| <1 $$
I have to prove that $\| . \|$ is strictly convex norm iff $ \forall z \in X$ and for any closed convex set C in X there is at most a one $x \in C $ such that $\|x-z\|=\inf\{\|y-z\| \mid y \in c\}$
I have tried that like this:
Let $\| . \|$ is strictly convex norm.
Let there exists $x_1,x_2 \in C $ that $\inf { \|y-z\| \mid y \in C } = \|x_1 -z\|=\|x_2 -z\|$
$$ \Rightarrow \| \frac {x_1 +x_2\}{2} - z\| = \| \frac{x_1 -z}{2} + \frac{x_2 -z}{2}\| \le \frac {1}{2} (\|x_1 -z\| + \|x_1 -z\|) =\inf \{ \|y-z\| \mid y \in C \} $$
Since C is convex then $\frac {x_1 +x_2\}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.x_1 +\frac{1}{2}.x_2 \in C$
Then by the definition of infimum
$$ \| \frac {x_1 +x_2\}{2} - z\|=\inf \{ \|y-z\| \mid y \in C \}= \|x_1 -z\|=\|x_2 -z\|$$
Let $ y_1 := \frac{x_1 -z}{\|x_1 -z\|}$ and $ y_2 := \frac{x_2 -z}{\|x_2 -z\|}$
$\Rightarrow \|y_1\|=\|y_2\|=1 $ and
$|\frac{y_1 +y_2}{2}|= \frac{1}{2}.|\frac{x_1 -z}{|x_1 -z|}+\frac{x_2 -z}{|x_2 -z|} |=\frac{1}{2|\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}-z|}.|x_+x_2-2z|=\frac{1}{|\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}-z|}.|\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}-z|=1 $$
and this is  a contradiction.
Now I have to prove that if $ \forall z \in X$ and for any closed convex set C in X there is at most a one $x \in C $ such that $\|x-z\|=\inf\{\|y-z\| \mid y \in c\}$ then  $\| . \|$ is strictly convex norm.
I tried to prove the contrapositive like this :
Let this norm is not strictly convex then there exists $x,y \in X $ such that $\| x\| \le 1,  \|y\| \le 1 $ and $\| \frac{x+y}{2} \| \ge 1$
$$ \frac{1}{2}(\|x\|+\|y\|) = \| \frac{x+y}{2}\| \ge 1 \Rightarrow \|x\|+\|y\| \ge 2 \Rightarrow \|x\|= 1 , \|y\|= 1 $$
$Let C:= \{tx+(1-t)y : t \in [0,1] \} $
It's clear that C is closed and convex set.
Let we take $z=0$ then we have to find
$$ inf \{ \|u\| \mid u \in C \}$$
for any $ u \in C, \exists t \in [0,1] $ such that :
$$ \|u\|=\| tx+(1-t)y \| \le t \|x\|+(1-t) \|y\| = t+1-t=1 $$
So,
$$ inf \{ \|u\| \mid u \in C \} \le 1$$
But I can't use that for this proving.
Any help??!!

Every norm is convex (you can prove this by triangular inequality), so if 3 aligned points have norm 1, all points in their segment have norm 1, but the segment itself is closed and convex

@Exodd why is every norm is convex? for example in $R^2$ there is max norm that it is not convex for exapmle : $(1,0),(1,1) \in R^2 $ and $|(1,0)+(1,1)|=|(2,1)|=max {|2|,|1|}=2 >1 $ also I don't see how I can prove that if 3 aligned points have norm 1, all points in their segment have norm 1

Every norm is convex since by triangular inequality and linearity $$|tx + (1-t)y| \le t|x| + (1-t)|y| $$. Your counterexample is wrong because you need a $t\in [0,1]$ for a convex combination of points

You just need to prove that every point in $C$ has norm 1.
You already proved that $u\in C \implies \|u\|\le 1$.
Take now $u\in C$ and $v = x+y -u\in C$. We have that $(u+v)/2 = (x+y)/2$, so
$$1 = \| (x+y)/2\|  = \| (u+v)/2\| \le (\|u\| + \|v\|)/2\le 1 $$
and as a consequence, $\|u\| = \|v\| =  1$

why is this $v$ in in C?

if $u=tx + (1-t)y$ then $v =(1-t)x+ ty $

I got it. Thank you
